# The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'

Tags: flutter

The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.9 to 11.3.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

The project was build properly until FMDB cocoa pods updated and this error raised.
Solution Done So Far,

All these solution done mentioned in this link

https://fluttercorner.com/the-ios-deployment-target-iphoneos-deployment-target-is-set-to-8-0-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

Open

```
macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj
```

Search and replace

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6;
```

with

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.14;
```